# Move expired sql entries into another database at specific times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a rails website that involves shift management. I am using a separate database (`SQLlite3`) to archive past shifts because I will need to do operations on future/present shifts and I don't want them slowed down for seldom accessed archives. I want to automatically move each shift to the new database exactly when it ends.

I know I can use `cron` to check every so often, but is there a way to do it at the specific time? I don't need exact code, just a point in the right direction will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you measured the effect of "operations on future/present shifts" without moving past shifts to a different database? Do that first.

Comment: How many records do you anticipate for a shift? SQL DBMs are very fast when working with indexed records, so it's very conceivable you're worrying about premature optimization. Because SQLite can be file-based, why not have separate DBs for each shift and rotate through them as necessary, rather than try to move data in and out? Consider that if you outgrow SQLite and move to something like MySQL or PostgreSQL, that you want your code to work in the future without having to rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me I'd create an `ActiveRecord` callback, and then use it to schedule a background task using something like `sidekiq`

here's a sample code for demonstration

The shift class code:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :archive_shift, if: :shift_ended?

  private

  def archive_shift
    ShiftArchiver.perform_async(id)
  end

  def shift_ended?
    # some condition
  end
end
```

The archiver class code:

```
class ShiftArchiver
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(shift_id)
    # archiving code
  end
end
```

This way the archiving code will only run when the shift has ended, and will run in the background so it won't block any requests.

More about [sidekiq over here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq#sidekiq)

Comment: Perfect answer thank you. I wish I had enough points to upvote.

Comment: you could mark the question as correct, from the checkmark below the vote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your first part of the question about `SQL`. However, about `cron`in Linux (if this is what you are asking). You can call `cron` at every interval time or at specific time e.g.

if you want to call a script at 18:00 hrs

```
0 18 * * * root bash /pvt/scripts/stat.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

if you want to call a script at 03:35 hrs

```
35 3 * * * root bash /pvt/scripts/stat.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

if you want to call a script at every 5 minutes

```
*/5 0 * * * root bash /pvt/scripts/stat.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

So, if you want to call your script at specific time, you can surely do this using `cron`.